# Steam error logs are huge!

Tags: 18.04, steam, log

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 and use Steam regularly.
I just noticed that the file `$HOME/.steam/error.log` weighs **86GB** (!!!) and seems full of the following line:

```
type unknown not a basic type
```

Is there a way to limit the size of the error logs? Is this the case for other users, or is this a bug that I should report to Steam?

Comment: How old is the file? You haven't given us enough of the error.log file to make any determination. Upload more (not all 86G) to paste.ubuntu.com. After you do that, delete the error.log file, and let it create a newer/smaller error.log file, and it should be easier to evaluate.

Comment: Have you tried restarting Steam? It did that to me with a file in /tmp/dumps/ after an update, a restart fixed it and removed the file. Maybe you will need to kill the process manually.

Comment: same here! so its probably a steam bug